# Get x amount of initial digits in a long Number

Tags: swift, string, decimal

I have some numbers coming from the api like this: `0.0000000092726851369802`

How can I get the index (which can change) of the last 0 before the 9 and from there count 4 and return those numbers? So it would look like: `0.000000009272` returning only the 4 last values after the 0s

Looking for a Swift 5 solution

Comment: yep, I will convert that number to currency which will be a string, that string will be presented to the user @matt

Comment: First you should only use the string initializer otherwise you will loose its precision. Make sure to receive this as string

Comment: It seems to me that if this was in scientific notation you had the information you want (the significant digits) and you threw it away. The conversion to Decimal is the problem. Please show the actual string you got from the server, not some intermediate crud you created.

Comment: no, before I do `Decimal(xx)` it would show something like this: `2.28e-06` @matt

Comment: Yup so there is your answer. `228` are the digits you want. Now just prepend zeroes and you're done.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean? @matt

Comment: Anyway 2.28e-06 is not 0.0000000092726851369802 so where the heck did that come from?

Comment: yeah I used another value as example, I fixed it @matt

Comment: So there you go. Do not convert anything. Do all your work directly on the string. 9.272685136 is the mantissa. Take the first four digits. e-9 is the exponent. It tells you how many zeros to prepend. Done. No Decimal needed.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind to get it is a dumb approach: convert it to string, get the first 5 characters, ex:  `9.272` then convert it to Int while doing `9.272*1000` and then appending the number of 0s you mentioned, is this the right approach or is there something simpler? @matt

Comment: You do not have to convert it to a string. It is a string. Do not convert it to decimal or Int or anything else.

Comment: originally it wasn't I'm doing multi-currency, but you just made me realize I should convert it to currency after I do this. So yea it would be a String. I'll work on the solution @matt

Comment: Actually... there is only 1 value that comes with scientific notation, the rest come as Double from the api with that large number, so in this case that I don't have the scientific notation how would I do it? I have it coming from the api like this: `0.0000000092726851369802`, I modified the question to discard the scientific notation because I can get that part using another way in Double @matt

Comment: If you do not tell the truth about the problem it is hard to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@available(macOS 12.0, iOS 15.0, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0, *)

You can use formatted method and set the number precision significant digits to four:

```
let decimal = Decimal(string: "9.272685136e-9")!
decimal.formatted(.number.precision(.significantDigits(4)))  // "0.000000009273"
```

For older iOS versions you can create a custom Numeric formatter as follow:

---

```
extension Formatter {
    static let significantDigits: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.usesSignificantDigits = true
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

---

```
extension Numeric {
    func maximumSignificantDigits(_ digits: Int = 4) -> String {
        Formatter.significantDigits.maximumSignificantDigits = digits
        return Formatter.significantDigits.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
}
```

---

```
let decimal = Decimal(string: "9.272685136e-9")!
decimal.maximumSignificantDigits()  // "0.000000009273"
```

Comment: Hi leo, thanks for the answer, as I was telling matt I have only 1 value from the api coming with the scientific notation, how would it be in case I have a double with a number like: `0.0000000092726851369802`?

Comment: I tested it really quick and it works flawlessly! I'll be conducting more tests later on. Thank you!

Comment: @Arturo check my last edit

Comment: Tomorrow I'll check it, I'm trying to solve a bug. Thanks for the edit :)